# Get cart items and subtotal value in static block

Tags: static-block, header

I want to get cart items and total value in my custom block section.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('custom_block_id')->toHtml()  ?>
```

I called it in header.phtml.

This is my image tracking pixel for bronto

```
 <img alt=""
 src="http://www.example.com/public/?q=stream_conversion&amp;fn=Mail_Conversion&amp;id=blbimmbjoskvkqnahjntpjzmoqpsbdd&amp;type=$&amp;description='{{cart_items}}'&amp;money='{{cart_subtotal}}'"
 height="0" width="0" />
```

Instead of `cart_items` and `cart_subtotal` I want actual data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can access current **quote** wherever you want this way

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

Then, for instance, you can access **subtotal** this way (see `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar` class)

```
public function getSubtotal($skipTax = true)
{
    $subtotal = 0;
    $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
    $config = Mage::getSingleton('tax/config');
    if (isset($totals['subtotal'])) {
        if ($config->displayCartSubtotalBoth()) {
            if ($skipTax) {
                $subtotal = $totals['subtotal']->getValueExclTax();
            } else {
                $subtotal = $totals['subtotal']->getValueInclTax();
            }
        } elseif($config->displayCartSubtotalInclTax()) {
            $subtotal = $totals['subtotal']->getValueInclTax();
        } else {
            $subtotal = $totals['subtotal']->getValue();
            if (!$skipTax && isset($totals['tax'])) {
                $subtotal+= $totals['tax']->getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return $subtotal;
}
```

About **cart_items**, you'd define the desired format: do you want product IDs, maybe the sku? Only for visible items (configurable, etc...)? You'd take a look to collection returned by `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems()`

**update**

A working example... As you'd know you can execute php in .phtml files. So you can get all data you need

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
// print_r($quote->getData()); 
// uncomment the line above to check different stored values for subtotal
$skus = array();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem){
    // maybe you'd want to clean some of the skus, due to complex products
    $skus[] = $quoteItem->getSku();
}   
?>
```

Then just replace your params in your pixel code, for instance (list of comma separated skus)

```
...description='<?php echo implode(',', $skus);?>'...
```

Sorry if I was rude in my comment, but I prefer to explain how to get things better than just copy/pasting the concrete answer. If you want to work with Magento, you'd prefer to learn how things work rather than just getting the solution, believe me

Comment: Actually my static block is displaying well. I want to display the products and subtotal along with the  block values. Means if I add a pen worth 20 that should come like this.
 <img alt=""
 src="http://www.example.com/public/?q=stream_conversion&amp;fn=Mail_Conversion&amp;id=blbimmbjoskvkqnahjntpjzmoqpsbdd&amp;type=$&amp;description='{{sku-pen-01}}'&amp;money='{{20}}'"
 height="0" width="0" />

Is it a proper method?
How can I do that?

Comment: My answer explains how to get quote info from any phtml template, and explore quote data. You'd play with Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems() and get the info you need

Comment: I've updated my answer, with some example code